# AWS Textract PDF to JSON Key Value Pair Confusion

Tags: amazon-textract

I'm trying to follow this AWS example.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/automatically-extract-content-from-pdf-files-using-amazon-textract.html#extract-PDF-content-using-amazon-textract-resources

after the first run you need to create TemplateJSON.json others. In the Juypter notebook it says there is an example of this file but I don't see one.

[image]

Does anyone have an example of what this key value json should look like?

I tried adding Filename_FormTable_parseTableHeader.json to TemplateJSON.json like this but it did not work. [image]